# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < and Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the following code on myscript.js file.

```
 `<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Paragraph Changed";
}
</script>`
```

Then linked the myscript.js as external javascript file on my external.html page.The code of  external.html is following:
   `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1/javascript/myscript.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>My Webpage</h1>
    <p id="demo">This is a Paragraph.</p>
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="myFunction()">
    </body>
    </html>`

If i put those files on my localhost javascript folder, Google Chrome gives me the errors:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (myscript.js:1)
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined (external.html:10)

Mozilla Firefox gives me the errors:
SyntaxError: syntax error (myscript.js:1)
ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined (external.html:1)

If i write the myscript.js codes inside external.html file and click the button i get no error. The error occurred when i try to run the html file with external myscript.js file. I have googled this problem several times and did not get the answer. Please help me.

Comment: Sounds like you got the URL to the script wrong.

Comment: Try googling "linking an external javascript file in html".

Comment: Take off the script tags from the file myscript.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An external script shall be pure javascript code and must not contain the tokens

```
 `<script>
```

and

```
</script>`
```

Do only place the following in your `myscript.js` file:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Paragraph Changed";
}
```